# Windows API ReadFile Drops Null Characters (Serial Port)

Tags: visual-c++, serial-port

I am using ReadFile to read a null character '0x00', but it is not able to see it.

If I send "0x01 0x02 0x00 0x03" to my program. It will receive "0x01 0x02 0x03". I know for a fact that my sending side is sending the null character (I used a scope to see the data).

I have checked the DCB structure and have fNull set to false. (which is supposed to allow for null bytes to be received and not discarded)

This is the configuration of the DCB shown from GetCommState:

```
    DCBlength   28
    BaudRate    9600
    fBinary 1   
    fParity 0
    fOutxCtsFlow    0   
    fOutxDsrFlow    0   
    fDtrControl 0   
    fDsrSensitivity 0   
    fTXContinueOnXoff   0   
    fOutX   1
    fInX    1   
    fErrorChar  0
    fNull   0
    fRtsControl 0
    fAbortOnError   0
    fDummy2 0
    wReserved   0
    XonLim  2048
    XoffLim 512 
    ByteSize    7
    Parity  0
    StopBits    2
    XonChar 0 '\0'  
    XoffChar    0 '\0'  
    ErrorChar   0 '\0'  
    EofChar 0 '\0'
    EvtChar 0 '\0'
    wReserved1  0
```

Am I missing something in the structure that might be blocking the null character as well? or is it possible it's a driver configuration or registry configuration that I need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have XON/XOFF flow control enabled and have specified null as the XON/XOFF characters.  That is why you are not seeing null data bytes.  You need to set the `fOutX` and `fInX` fields to 0 instead of 1.

Comment: My understanding of this area is a little fuzzy. But if I am just transmitting over two lines TX/RX, then I can't use the Hardware flow control and will need to use Software flow control which would mean that I need a XON/XOFF character of some sort. correct?

Comment: I realized my problem. I was not using the dedicated XON/XOFF characters in ASCII (17 and 19) and instead was accidentally setting them to 0 when I created a new DCB structure.