# WinAPI ReadFile stops when reaching null

Tags: c, winapi, readfile

I'm trying to write a very simple win32 program. I open a file for reading using *CreateFile()*, and then read it's content using *ReadFile()*

```
HANDLE hfile=CreatFileW(L"Capturejpg.jpg", GENERIC_READ, 0,
              NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
bReadResult=ReadFile(hFile, ReadBuff, BUFFERSIZE-1, &dwBytes, &OL);
```

when I'm reading a .txt file for example, this works just fine, the problem is when the file I am reading contains NULL (which is the case with most files) then *ReadFile* function stops reading(or maybe writing bytes to `ReadBuff`) when reaching the first NULL.
before asking I searched and found two answers.

1. **use something other that char array and char ***: for this, I don't know what else I can use, cause my goal is to read the file and search for the files extension(for example if it's .gif then the first 3 characters read "Gif")
2. **change DCB**: the problem with this one is that I have no idea what DCB is actually, how to change it, and change exactly what in it.

**EDIT:** other posts with the same problem: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152890/) and [this one](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ff323ec6-6ce4-457d-9fcd-9ba801ed425c/readfile-problem-with-pipe?forum=vcmfcatl)

Comment: `ReadFile` of course not stop reading or writing bytes to `ReadBuff` on **any** byte

Comment: How do you know that `ReadFile` isn't reading all the requested bytes?  You need to post a complete example demonstrating your error.

Comment: You misdiagnosed the issue. The bug is in the code where you are trying to display the data, not in the code you read the data. This would be immediately evident, had you provided a [mcve]. Anyway, voting to close, because this has been asked a billion times. Down-voted for lack of research, too.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33586466/1889329

Comment: What's the value of `dwBytes` after the read ?

Comment: @IInspectable turns out you are right, sorry guys. 
BTW for other people with the same problem my mistake was that I was using MultiByteToWideChar to be able to show it in MessageBox easily but i was doing it like `MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_PRECOMPOSED, ReadBuff, -1, lpWideBuff, dwFileSize)` and the -1 would cause it to stop with the first NULL character

Comment: Even if had provided the length explicitly, that would still be wrong. Binary data is not meant to be human readable. It will contain non-printable characters. Not every chunk of bytes can be interpreted as a human readable string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ReadFile` does not care one bit about the content that it reads. It will quite happily read zero bytes and continue reading beyond that point in the file. It wouldn't be much use if it could not do that.

You have just misdiagnosed the problem. You have read into a character array `ReadBuffer` and then printed like this:

```
printf("%s", ReadBuffer);
```

Now, `printf` will indeed stop when it reaches a zero byte. You will need to find some other way to output the content of this file.